# How to directly access php file in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have a php file that generate js code. I need to acces this file like host/nameoffile?args

For now I settled this issue this way - a have named my php like page-{slug}.php, made a page in Wordpress with same slug and placed this file in my current theme folder.

our server works on nginx with only one entry point that is index.php, so it's block any other php queries.

Is there any other realization, not like my current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution by @parham is that, what i was looking for)

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse131387_template_redirect' );
function wpse131387_template_redirect( ){
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/some-template') {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->is_404 = false;
        status_header(200);
        include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/some-template.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: it's better to say
`if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/some-template')==0)`
cause there are maybe args

Answer (score 1):

how about coping all the code from the php file and adding them to a function with parameters (in functions.php) that would return the js code. That way you can just call the function from the header/footer and it will output the relevant js code.

Comment: looks great, but with such solution i lose possibility to call my code like
`<script src="{host}/{filename}?{args}"></script>`
and i need to call exactly this way (